# Time series CV when not using past targets as features

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

Imagine you have a time series dataset, e.g. price returns of a set of stocks over time. You want to predict the price returns of a stock, given only non-price data of the stock for that date (so, for example, recent changes in price or previous price levels would not be in your feature set, but various fundamental parameters, forward predictors of the parameters, historical changes of those parameters would be in the feature set).

In this case, each training example is self-contained, but nearby examples for the same stock would be very near in feature space and probably have very close outputs. What would be a good approach for cross-validation here? Train on all the data for one set of stocks, and validate/test on another group of stocks? But that ignores the time component entirely and even different stocks can be correlated.

Should we use leave-one-time-period CV? Like here, but without the restriction that all training time periods have to be from earlier time periods than the validation one:
[image]

As far as I understand it, that restriction is here because if past values of the output are used in training, then the model will already have some information about past outputs and the results would be biased on past time periods. But then it seems that if you do not use past targets in training, that restriction is not needed. If that is the right approach, then how does one pick the appropriate "gap" between the training examples and the validation time period?